# How to import css modules to Framer?

Tags: css, reactjs, import, mantine

I developed locally a component that works and uses:

```
import "@mantine/core/styles.css";
import "@mantine/carousel/styles.css";
```

When I check to component in [framer](https://framer.com/projects/) it works in the demo, however when built, the site display this error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
> the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type
> checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I assume this is because this is not the way to import this. But then what is?